# Checking if a string starts with another string

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement

Simple enough issue but I cannot seem to solve it. I need the below to be True.

```
var1="was shot by skeleton"
var2="was shot by"

if [ "$var1" == "$var2" ]; then
    echo "true"; else
    echo "false"
fi
```

I have Tried putting "*" beside var2 but no luck.

Thanks, 
Simon

Answer (score 1):

Try double brackets :

```
if [[ "$var1" == *"$var2"* ]]; then
.....
```

Comment: Yep that worked! Could you explain why? Thanks!

Comment: great... here is some info... http://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash ...